# how to rotate elements to the left in array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to rotate an array to the left, for example rotateLeft3([1, 2, 3]) → [2, 3, 1]

Here is my solution, but it's not working for some reason. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool six;
    int Array[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int x = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0]);
    int temp = Array[0];
    int temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        Array[i] = Array[i + 1];
        Array[x - 1] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << Array[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your biggest problem is, that you don't run it in debugger, step by step, to see where exactly it is failing. Otherwise you were quite close, just overwriting the last value too soon and too many times, and going beyond array boundary due to wrong end condition in `for`. Both problems can/should be spotted in debugger, keep playing with your old code, until you learn how to use debugger to spot such things.

Comment: You mean `Shift Your Array By One To The Right`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be right approach.
So do following changes in your code,
1)   Change the Loop Condition to end `(x-1)` (otherwise it will be out of bound)
2)   Remove the temp assignment inside loop
3) Assign value after the loop ends.

```
int temp = Array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < x-1; i++){
    Array[i] = Array[i + 1];
}
Array[x-1] = temp;
```

OR 
if you want to use inbuilt template then use [std::rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) in [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header

Answer (score 4):

Use the [std::rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) defined in the [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header.

Edit:

A better link is [here, along with an implementation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: I think advising somebody learning how to program (and failing even at something as simple as own version of array rotation) to use library is pointless. What's the benefit of blindly using something you don't understand? And when you finally get to the problem, which is not solved directly in library, it will be probably so complex, that without those basics already learnt one would be completely lost.

Comment: @Ped7g Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Ped7g The link shows an implementation, not just the `std::rotate` function.  Too many times, a poster gets things so wrong, the best answer is just to show them how it's done and have them study it.

Comment: That's nice bonus (and worth of look of OP, I agree), but the question was where he went wrong. You are answering that quite indirectly IMO, or almost not answering it at all. Agree to disagree sounds OK to me. :)

Answer (score 4):

With `std::rotate`, it would be

```
std::rotate(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RMMDCY)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Complete the rotLeft function below.
vector<int> rotLeft(vector<int> a, int d) {
    int temp=0;
    int size = a.size();
    /*if shifts are more than size of array*/
    /*example if d=8 size=5 
    then result will be 8%5=3 left shift only*/
    d = d%size;
    int shift = size-d;
    bool r = false;
    /*here i am taking decision whether i have to do right shift or left shift*/
    /*if size=5 d=4 
    then we can do right shift to 1*/
    if(d > shift)
    {
        d = shift;
        r = true;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        /*do right shift*/
        if(r == true)
        {
            temp = a[size-1];
            for(int j=size-1;j>0;j--)
            {
                a[j] = a[j-1];
            }
            a[0] = temp;
        }
        /*do left shift*/
        else
        {
            temp = a[0];
            for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
            {
                a[j] = a[j+1];
            }
            a[size-1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the best way is to use std::rotate for this purpose